# Convert text column in date mysql issue

Tags: mysql

I have a text column named `arrival_date` and a date column `arrival`.
the `arrival_date` text has a format like: 30/01/2018.

I want to save in the `arrival` column the transformed text to date from the `arrival_date`.

What i do is:

```
UPDATE table SET arrival = DATE_FORMAT(arrival_date, "%d-%m-%Y")
```

I get the error:

```
Error Code: 1292. Incorrect datetime value: '20/01/2018'
```

Comment: Maybe you should cast it as date.

Comment: @McNets still the same output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a mysql `STR_TO_DATE` function to convert from string to date:

```
STR_TO_DATE(arrival_date, '%d/%m/%Y')
```

So with your code:

```
UPDATE table SET arrival = STR_TO_DATE(arrival_date, '%d/%m/%Y')
```

Comment: I had already answered this question, but thanks, the OP wanted hyphen separated format

Comment: @jimmy8ball There is nothing to do with the hyphen. The issue is to convert a date from a string. Since the OP's string use the dash, this is the correct answer.

Comment: Downvoter should explain Why! since this is actually the right answer.

Comment: @jimmy8ball Please read the documentation (see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date), the second argument of `STR_TO_DATE` is the format of the given string. Since the OP string use dash and not hyphen, your answer was wrong.

Comment: @JorgeCampos Life is unfair sometimes, thanks for the support !

Comment: @A.D Hi there, and welcome to Stackoverflow. Since this is the right answer consider in accepting it. You do so by clicking in the V icon at the left side. And please consider in also giving the answer an upvote (by clicking in the up arrow) since someone unfairly downvoted it.